# How to store GameObject.position in to the new array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject array, how can I store the GameObject.position into the new array by using a float[]?

I try to use the below code, but it's not working...

```
public float[] Storeposition;
public GameObject[] Go;

public save(){
   storeposition = new float[Go.count * 3]
   for(int i = 0; i < Go.count; i++){ 
       for(int b = 0; b < (Go.count * 3); b++){ 
       storeposition[b] = Go[i].transform.position.x;
       storeposition[b + 1] = Go[i].transform.position.y;
       storeposition[b + 2] = Go[i].transform.position.z;
       b = b + 2
}
}
}
```

Comment: You know, the third part of the `for` loop does not have to be `something++`. It can be any expression. `b += 3` would work fine there.

Comment: Also, please consider sharing what is not working. And stepping through your code with a debugger makes wonders.

Comment: Why not store them as `Vector3` though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector3 allows indexing to access the individual components of the vector

```
var myVector3 = new Vector3(4, 5, 6);

var xComponent = myVector3[0]; // 4
var yComponent = myVector3[1]; // 5
var zComponent = myVector3[2]; // 6
```

This helps us simplify the for loop by accessing each component directly using the current iterator.

```
var positions = new float[gameObjects.Length * 3];

for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
    {
        positions[i * 3 + ii] = gameObjects[i].transform.position[ii];
    }
}
```